# Android device leaks SSIDs

Tags: wifi, android

I suspect that an android device is trying all SSIDs it was ever connected during wifi scan. 1) It alone gives enough information to identify the device 2) If a network with no encryption is saved, a MitM attack can be performed.

Is there a way to handle it? E.g. trying only networks that are in the range (listen for beacons). It will make impossible to connect to hidden SSIDs, but who uses it?

Comment: Disable Wi-Fi, unless you are at home with secure network. And generally, open networks are dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

> I suspect that an android device is trying all SSIDs it was ever connected during wifi scan. 1) It alone gives enough information to identify the device 2) If a network with no encryption is saved, a MitM attack can be performed.

This would be typical of most mobile devices if you store the connection in a way where it will automatically connect again at a future time.

> Is there a way to handle it?

Yes. You can do so by doing whatever combination of the below you like. This will at least limit your exposure.

- Don't store you wireless networks so you can connect automatically in the future.
- Delete wireless networks when you are done.
- Disable wireless on your device when you don't want to be connected.

> E.g. trying only networks that are in the range (listen for beacons).

In comments elsewhere, you seem to find "passive scanning only" as an appealing solution. This will significantly increase times for a device to connect to a wireless network (from your reported 3+ seconds to something more like 6-20+ seconds) and have the potential to create what appear to users as "outages" of similar periods every time the device scans to check for better networks to which they can roam.

Put simply, it won't happen. Why? Because it is asking for developers to add a feature that (a) decreases usability by increasing time taken to find/connect to networks and (b) impacts modern devices more significantly than legacy devices. Or put another way, how many users do you think would be pushing developers to "significantly increase the times it takes to connect to a wireless network"?

Automatically trying to connect to any configured SSID as if were hidden was a change made to simplify the user experience and make it easier for the masses. As in many such feature decisions, this does come at a cost for potential security/privacy issues. You will find little support in developer circles for going back on this decision and increase the number of [confusing] choices people [with little technical knowledge] need to make when connecting to a wireless network.

A better and more likely suggestion that you could make is an option (global or per profile) to "allow connections to hidden networks" that would be enabled by default and provide the existing behavior. Knowledgeable users could then choose to disable it if they wanted, and the active scanning for networks taking place could do so without including an SSID. No negative impact from disabling active scanning necessary.

Still a tough sell since there are many features users [in larger numbers] want for their devices and developers tend to follow the demand, but more viable than the prior suggestion.

> It will make impossible to connect to hidden SSIDs, but who uses it?

Many organizations do and some home users. Personally I find very few cases where it is used for a valid reason, but my opinion doesn't stop people from using hidden SSIDs.

Comment: "but who uses it" means there may be an option for a feature which has more privaca but don't allow users to connect to APs with hidden ssids and many users can use it. I personally never had to connect to an AP with hidden ssid.

Comment: *the device scans to check for better networks to which they can roam.* - yes, roaming may be a problem too if scans has to be made on other channels since waiting on another channel means temporary disconnect.

Comment: *easier for the masses* - well, I never claimed it would be a solution for every housewife. That's why I spoke about an option.

Comment: Just because you haven’t used a feature is immaterial. You probably haven’t used the majority of features in your devices/software, yet there are many people who do. You are asking for a feature to be developed that is moving backwards (geared for older tech and reducing usability). You are never going to get traction for such a feature unless you code it in yourself, but it will never hit mainstream distribution. I offered an alternative giving a solution for what you want and which doesn’t move backwards, yet you still seem to want to argue for your flawed solution. So done here.

Comment: Nice try to teach me, but 1) I almost never seen hidden SSID's being used, 2) they has no security meaning. I know it will never be implemented just because noone gives a shit if users can be tracked. How many manufacturers have implemented MAC change? Well, your *"solution"* is even less usable.

Comment: Your [limited] experience is irrelevant. I have seen them used and unless you specifically look for them they don’t tend to appear in most devices available network lists. I agree they don’t serve a security purpose which is why I said they are rarely used for a valid reason. That doesn’t mean there aren’t valid reasons. My solution doesn’t adversely impact the scanning times, achieves the goal of not broadcasting previous SSIDs if you choose, and leaves the ease of usability for the typical user who doesn’t understand or care about the issue. Why would you call that less usable than yours?

Comment: Because you'll need to enter password every time??

Comment: @SmitJohnth, my suggested solution has no need to enter a password, only two of the three available solutions I provide may. Please actually read the post: *A better and more likely suggestion that you could make is an option (global or per profile) to "allow connections to hidden networks" that would be enabled by default and provide the existing behavior.*

Comment: I already mentioned it above *"means there may be an option for a feature which has more privaca but don't allow users to connect to APs with hidden ssids and many users can use it."*

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution will not work since the attacker is sending out malicious beacons.

In Android you can forget networks that don't have security. Don't know if you can do this automatically. On my one plus there is no option to not remember networks. Maybe there are apps that can do this for you.

Comment: It could work against leaking of identifying information.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. It would require to change the driver that sends out these beacons. So it's not something you can do easily. Also, take into account the frequency of these broadcasts from the access point. It might take much longer for a device to connect if you rely only on these broadcasts.

Comment: Beacons are sent at least 10 times per second. I don't think it will be a big loss.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, you might think 100ms isn't long, but the reason passive scanning is considered inefficient is that a client needs to scan every channel and typically wait at least 100ms (up to 200ms to cover longer beacon intervals) to ensure it has found available APs. If you take the US and exclude DFS channels, you have 26 channels which gives you nearly 3-6 seconds of scanning time. If you include the DFS channels or in a different region, this number can easily climb upwards to 10+ seconds before even establishing a connection. Bad enough when connecting, but when the client wants to roam?

Comment: @YLearn how have you got 26 channels? 3+ seconds is typical connect time on my android device. Can't say anything about roaming, never used it. At least my suggestion can be an option.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, based on US FCC specifications, you have 11 2.4GHz channels and 15 5GHz channels. Include the DFS channels and that is about 30 more in 5GHz, so you can double the 3-6 second scanning time. That is just finding the networks and not even beginning the connection attempt. As for roaming, every 802.11 client uses it. It will always spend some of its time looking for a better network/AP to connect (stronger signal, less utilized, etc). Whether you have multiple APs or not is immaterial. The client will still scan for them.

Comment: @YLearn 2,4 GHz and 5 GHz wifi can be operated simultaneously. Well, 5GHz regulations are very different across countries. As I already said, my device needs 3+ seconds to connect, so what's the difference?

Comment: @YLearn probably my solution is not the best, I'm not a network expert. But something must be done to prevent device identification.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, yes they can be operated simultaneously *if you have two radios and two sets of antennas*. To my knowledge, the vast majority of client devices (especially mobile devices dependent on battery life) only have a single radio and a single set of antennas. The difference between 3+ seconds (your connection time) and 12+ seconds (generous difference between active and passive scanning times with all channels plus connection time) is quite significant for most users who want to wake up their device and start using it immediately. Many of them will tell you 3+ seconds is too long.

Comment: @YLearn that's why I said it can be made as option. Most of 5 GHz channels are not allowed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_.28802.11a.2Fh.2Fj.2Fn.2Fac.29 And IMHO 5 GHz is not that popular.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, not sure what you are reading, but it must not be that link. According to that link, other references and FCC rulings, most of the channels listed on Wikipedia certainly are allowed. As for 5GHz not being popular, have you heard of 802.11ac? 802.11ac wave 1 adoption was incredibly fast among mobile device manufacturers due to it's increased power efficiency (i.e. longer battery life). 802.11ac only operates in 5GHz....there is no 802.11ac in 2.4GHz. In my experience managing wireless networks, the 5GHz devices now outnumber the 2.4GHz devices.

Comment: @YLearn surely I've heard, but I have a laptop with a-wifi and I see like 1 AP in 5 GHz. I have to see ac AP's, right?

Comment: @SmitJohnth, just because *you* only see one 5GHz AP wherever you are doesn't mean much for a number of reasons. Five years ago, the majority of clients on most wireless networks were 2.4GHz, today that has flipped. I just pulled a report for the last day on an 802.11n (no ac) wireless network I have management access to and of over 17k devices, 56% were 5GHz. 802.11ac devices do support 802.11b/g/n for use when 2.4GHz is necessary. However, you can't have an 802.11ac device without having 5GHz. You also won't get the power saving advantages or the performance advantages of 802.11ac on 2.4GHz.

Comment: @YLearn for me personally the solution I proposed were acceptable. My device cannot into ac. For people with devices without ac too.